# How to make a double line table border in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I have to make a double line table border in iTextSharp so far I manged to make a border appear only on special places with this code:

```
cell.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
```

but the border is a single line, is there a method that can create double line table border. 
I tried to put make it like this:

```
cell.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER |  Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER ;
```

but doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using nested tables? here's an example: http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/examples/Chap1010.pdf

You can possibly try to nest your table in a 1x1 parent table.

Here's the code for the above PDF: http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/examples/Chap1010.cs

From this page: http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examples.html

What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: Another option would be to use a PdfPCellEvent.

Comment: Seems the link is down.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
cell.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
```